# Hibernate flush is not throwing StalestateException for stale object( except first time flush call)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an object with composite ID. Program is doing following.

- Step 1. Read object from database.
- Step 2. Changed the 1-2 fields of key. Set blank.
- Step 3. Called flush(). It throws a `StaleStateException`.
- Step 4. Again called the flush().  It is not throwing
  `StaleStateException` for one case while throwing for others.

As per my understanding if a stale object is attached to session then flush should always throw `StaleStateException` unless we clear the session.

Is there some other factor ( other than clear) which is affecting my step 4. I want to know why it is not throwing `StaleStateException` for subsequent calls.

Comment: Thanks Tiny for formatting it.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-exceptions):

> If the Session throws an exception, including any SQLException, immediately rollback the database transaction, call Session.close() and discard the Session instance. Certain methods of Session will not leave the session in a consistent state. No exception thrown by Hibernate can be treated as recoverable. Ensure that the Session will be closed by calling close() in a finally block.

You're trying to use the session after an exception has been thrown, and that will lead to unpredictable behavior, as documented.

Comment: Actually it is long running transaction and the object throwing StaleStateException is optional for us  that is why we caught the exception and move ahead.                                                          In one case it is consistently working. I tried 45 times but in other case it failing every time. I suspect there is some other factor also affecting this might be refreshing the session.

Comment: The fact that the transaction is long or not, or that the object is optional or not, doesn't change anything: you're using the Session in a way that is explicitely documented as not usable.